# Fill ListView dynamically with tabcontrol

Tags: c#, linq, listview

I have five tabs. Each tab has its own table. I want to fill all the tabs with one function. That function fires on SelectedIndexChanged

How can I select the table in the current tab? I need it to fill all the tables dynamically.

I have tried this with LINQ:

```
Controls.OfType<ListView>()
    .FirstOrDefault(c => c.TabIndex == tabControl.SelectedIndex);
```

But ofcourse this does not work.
Help is appreciated.

Comment: have you tried calling this recursively for nested controls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a form `Controls`, use [TabControl.SelectedTab](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.selectedtab(v=vs.110).aspx) `Controls` like this

```
var listView = tabControl.SelectedTab.Controls.OfType<ListView>().FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I was just gonna answer this as an answer to my own question. Just figured it out, I have the exact same line of code. Thanks though. This will work for my code, but when you have multiple tables in a tab you might need to change the `.FirstOrDefault()` part for another.

Answer (score 0):

Handle the `Selected` event of your `TabControl` and recursively search for your `ListView`. This works even if it is nested in another control e.g. a `GroupBox`

```
private void tabControl1_Selected(object sender, TabControlEventArgs e)
{
    ListView listView = this.FindListView(e.TabPage.Controls);
}

private ListView FindListView(Control.ControlCollection controls)
{
    ListView result = null;
    foreach (Control control in controls)
    {
        result = control as ListView;
        if (result == null)
        {
            result = FindListView(control.Controls);
        }
        if (result != null)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```